# Finding the probability that the matrix has full rank

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

> There are only two entries, $0$ and $1$, over $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Thus,
>   only $16$ possible $2\times 2$ matrices over $Z_2$, and $6$ of them
>   have full rank:
>
> $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\   1&0\end{pmatrix}  \quad \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\  
> > 1&0\end{pmatrix}  \quad \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\   1&0\end{pmatrix}  \quad
> > \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\   1&1\end{pmatrix}  \quad \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\  
> > 0&1\end{pmatrix}  \quad \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\   0&1\end{pmatrix}$
>
> Randomly generate a $n\times n$ matrix over $\mathbb {Z}_2$ (where n
>   is big, say, $1000$). What's the probability that the matrix has full
>   rank?

I'd want to talk something regarding to this question.

I found the probability is equal to:

$\dfrac{(2^n-1)(2^n-2)(2^n-2^2)...(2^n-2^{n-1})}{2^n} \tag{1}$

On other hand, what's difference between $2^n$ and $2^{n^2}$?

$\dfrac{(2^n-1)(2^n-2)(2^n-2^2)...(2^n-2^{n-1})}{2^{n^2}} \tag{2}$

Can you tell whether or not I'm wrong?

Regards!

Comment: Your probability is $> 1$ so you must be wrong

Comment: Do you mean the denominator to be $2^{n^2}?$

Comment: @stity I can't see any difference between them so far.

Comment: @saulspatz Absoulety, that's what I meant.

Comment: Then you should edit your question.

Comment: @saulspatz am  on it right now :)

Comment: See the new edit if necessary. I hope it's more clear.

Comment: Total number of matrices is $2^{n^2}$. But the challenging part is to count the full rank matrices among these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second formula seems correct to me.  The rows of the matrix must be linearly independent.  The first row can be any vector but the zero vector, so there are $2^n-1$ choices.  Suppose that $k$ linearly independent rows have been added.  The next row can be any vector not in the linear span of the the first $k$ rows.  Since these form a $k-$dimensional vector space over GF(2), there are $2^n-2^k$ choices for row $k+1.$

Since there are $2^{n^2}$ possible $n\times n$ matrices, the denominator should be $2^{n^2}$.

Comment: Which one seems correct? I mean do both seem correct?

Comment: @Busi See my edits.

Comment: However, why not $2^n$:?

Comment: Did you see the duplicate question I pointed out?

Comment: @Busi Because there are $2^{n^2}$ possible matrices, not $2^n$.  Why would you think it was $2^n?$  The fraction would be greater than $1$, so not a probability.